# TortoiseHg Apply a Patch

Tags: mercurial, patch, tortoisehg

TortoiseHg allows you to email a patch file of your changes to someone, but does it support applying patches?

If so, how do you apply a patch using TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

From Repository Explorer, Repository > Import...

Comment: Good call.  As of V1.0 patch importing is part is part of TortoiseHg

Answer (score 51):

It looks like there is no built-in support in TortoiseHg for this.  Try this from a command prompt:

```
hg import my-patch-file.patch
```

That should apply the patch to your Mercurial repo and working copy.

**First Stab Answer**

You should be able to right-click on the patch file and choose "Apply patch..." - that's how it works for other TortoiseX clients.  Make sure that you save the patch file to the same directory path it was generated from.

Downloading TortoiseHg 0.8.1 to test...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't see that option.

Comment: Yeah I downloaded it and it took me a while to find the "email patch" feature you were referring to.  Tinkering...

Comment: Nice. Use `--no-commit` parameter to avoid a commit.

Answer (score 10):

What may be also noteworthy is, that "Repository Explorer, Synchronize > Import..." (which internally does a "hg import") will automatically do a "**commit**" - this may not be always wanted behaviour.

Other possibility is to use unix "patch" command (on Windows perhaps use cygwin version) or use "hg import" directly with "--no-commit" option. Both will just make changes in working directory and you may review the changes and commit them later manually.

Answer (score 8):

In 1.0, from Workbench:
    Repository > Import...